# Mouse simulate drag and drop

Tags: c#, drag-and-drop, mousemove

I am trying to simulate a drag and drop with the mouse.
Currently the mouse is moving to the right places, it is even clicking down on the file, however when it goes to the next point it seems to not be dragging the file?

Here's what I have:

```
   MouseOperations.SetCursorPosition(myPoints[0].X, myPoints[0].Y);
            MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftDown);


            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            MouseOperations.SetCursorPosition(myPoints[1].X, myPoints[1].Y);

            Thread.Sleep(2000);

            MouseOperations.MouseEvent(MouseOperations.MouseEventFlags.LeftUp);
```

And the mouseOperations class is here:

http://pastebin.com/KtjTJi4b

Comment: Thread.Sleep makes your application freeze to my knowledge, so you won't be able to do drag something. Tell me if this helps

Comment: I don't think that should affect it, I just put in the Thread.Sleep for testing purposes so I could see each step in sequence.